# I can connect to my RDS host server but not my database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've made a MySQL database using AWS RDS.

Here is my code connecting to the server and printing the databases:

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='admin', password='********',
                              host='************.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com', port=3306)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

databases = ("show databases")
mycursor.execute(databases)
for (databases) in mycursor:
     print(databases)
```

It prints some standard databases that I assume are there by default.

('information_schema',)
('mysql',)
('performance_schema',)
('sys',)

If I include my database name in the above code, I get a "database not found" error.

Which is obvious, because my database is not listed.

No where can I find someone else with this problem and clearly I've made the database, how else would I have the host URL?

I tried opening up the security group to all traffic to make sure that that isn't the problem.

[Database on the AWS website is available and has a connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9AxX.png)

You can see that the database is available and that it recognises my connection.

Comment: Please copy/paste the code inline into your question.

Comment: The screenshot just shows your database instance, which you may have given a name. That is the name of the server, which is totally different from the databases inside MySQL. Think of the names in the AWS console like a sticker you would put on your laptop to identify/name the physical laptop. It has no bearing on the contents of the software running in that laptop. From what you have shown in your question you need to actually run a MySQL create database statement to create a logical database inside MySQL with the name you want.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you Mark for the solution and non-condesending explaination :)